# Technology section of stackexchange.com footer has broken formatting on iPad

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, footer, ios

It looks like, due to incorrect width calculation, the last column has moved to a new line:

> [image: footer]

I’m still using iPad, but there is no mobile version of stackexchange.com.

Meta.stackexchange.com footer looks correct:

> [image: mse.footer]

Comment: I was going to say can't reproduce, then realised you're still doing this on your iPad

Comment: Leave a link to that page plz

Comment: @nicael https://stackexchange.com/

Comment: I dont see it there

Comment: Ah ok, right, i shouldve clicked technology

Comment: Well, it is reproducible on my iPad :)